# Targeting a single report when using IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have the following code. 
All 20 objects seem to get created ok.
The first `foreach` then works fine and iterates through all 20.
The second example using `linq` works well aswell.

Is it then possible to target just one of the objects, using a property such as `ReportKey`, and run the method `RunThisReport` just for that object? Or, because I've used the type `IEnumerable<>` have I gone down a dead-end?

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

    var models = SelectReports("SELECT * FROM 20RecordTable");

     //1.running the method for each
    foreach(myReport x in models) {
        Console.WriteLine("Doubled key:{0}",  x.myReportKeyDoubled().ToString());
    }

    //2.linq sample
    var result = from sample in models
                    select sample.ReportName;
    foreach(string x in result) {
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(x));
    }

    //3. target a single report say reportKey 512 and run the method RunThisReport?

    Console.WriteLine("Press [enter] to exit");
    Console.Read();
}

static IEnumerable<myReport> SelectReports(string myCommandText) {

    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString;
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = myCommandText;
        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {

            while(reader.Read()) {
                yield return new myReport {

                    ReportKey = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ReportKey")),
                    ReportName  = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ReportName")),
                    ReportDescription  = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ReportDescription")),
                    ReportTechDescription = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ReportTechDescription "))

                };
            }
        }
    }
}

public class myReport {

    public int ReportKey { get; set; }
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public string ReportDescription { get; set; }
    public string ReportTechDescription { get; set; }

    public int myReportKeyDoubled() {
        return ReportKey*2;
    }
    public string RunThisReport(){
        return this.ReportName + " needs to be run via" + this.ReportTechDescription;
    }         
}
```

Comment: Any reason you avoid code like `(string) reader["ReportName"]`?

Comment: models.First(i => i.ReportKey == "YOUR-KEY-VALUE").RunThisReport();

Comment: @ta.speot.is to replace `reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ReportName"))` ?

Comment: @ta.speot.is +1 thanks - I've amended it now. So `.GetCardinal` is equivalent to `[]` ?

Comment: It's equivalent to `dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("field"))`, yes. If you go by the documentation the behaviour should be identical. If you go by the implementation then you can see that the behaviour is pretty much identical (at least for `SqlDataReader`) http://pastebin.com/h62QZpRi I say "pretty much" because using `GetString` in your code vs. `GetValue` via the `this[string name]` function results in slightly different code being executed. But a quick check suggests the effect is identical.

Comment: @ta.speot.is thanks - so the code running in the background in slightly different but in the context of my question the results are the same - but `[]` is certainly more concise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var report = models.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ReportKey == 512);

 if (report != null)
     report.RunThisReport();
```

Or with comprehension syntax (ugly, yes?):

```
var report = (from m in models
              where m.ReportKey == 512
              select m).SingleOrDefault();
```

BTW with [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) your code will look like:

```
static IEnumerable<myReport> SelectReports(string myCommandText) 
{    
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString;
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        return conn.Query<myReport>(myCommandText);    
    }
}
```

Dapper is available via NuGet. And it's my choice when working with ADO.NET

Comment: SingleOrDefault takes a predicate.

Comment: I often do as well, but R# calls it out for me.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using "models.Where(m => m.ReportKey == 512).SingleOrDefault()" instead of "models.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ReportKey == 512)"?
Edit: too late:)

Comment: does the answer to this question need to include `lambda` syntax? is there an alternative; I'm not complaining just new to `C#`

Comment: @whytheq nope, operators `First`, `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, etc available only via fluent interface, so mixing comprehension syntax with linq operators is not very nice, but I can show you example

Comment: @whytheq Lamda syntax looks hard but it's not.  You know how for loops often look like for(int i; i < someValue; i++) think of how i represents the current loop index.  It's really very similar in a lamda expression (i => i.SomeProperty) is the same as (currentIndex => currentIndex.SomeProperty).  There is a lot more to it but it can be made that simple.

Comment: `Extension methods` and `lambda expressions` are same. Comprehension Syntax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229187/linq-why-is-it-called-comprehension-syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
models.First(x => x.ReportKey == 42).RunThisReport();
```

Comment: what about `ReportKey == 128375443`?

Comment: @whytheq if report with such key not found, this method will throw `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky hence why you've used `SingleOrDefault` ?

Comment: @whytheq it returns single model, throws exception if there is more than one model in result sequence, and returns null if model was not found. I think this is a correct behavior when you searching something by key

Comment: @lazyberezovsky so in fact `.First` might be the best code for me to use as it will throw an error which will help highlight database problems p.s you suggested Head First C# to me about 9mths ago - I got 33% of the way through but now I'm doing a `VB.NET` course and tutor advised me to concentrate on that; can't wait to get back and finish working through it.

Comment: @whytheq yep, great book :) `First` says that it's OK to have several reports with same key. If it's not OK, then use `Single`. If it's OK, then maybe you need all reports with that key, instead of only first report?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - ok - `single` it is then

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly you're struggling with getting your objects using LINQ.  The easiest thing to do here is use LINQ extension methods.  I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
models.First(i => i.ReportKey == yourReportKey).RunThisReport();
```

Or to clarify what's going on here:

```
// Get the report that matches the key
myReport report = models.First(i => i.ReportKey == "YOUR-KEY-VALUE");

// Call RunThisReport for that report.
report.RunThisReport();
```

This also works for collections:

```
models.Where(i => i.ReportKey == yourReportKey).ForEach(report => report.RunThisReport());
```

Hope that helps!  If not please clarify your question and I'll be glad to help.