# Convert a left join LINQ query from Comprehension to Lambda syntax

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to convert below LINQ query from [Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6229187/2055187) to "Lambda" syntax, that is  table1.where().select().

```
from t1 in table1
from t2 in table2.Where(t2=>t2.Table1ID == t1.ID).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {t1.C1, t2.C2}
```

Above query will be translated to a left join in SQL without using the ugly Join keyword in LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinqPad gives this translation:

```
Table1
   .SelectMany (
      t1 => 
         Table2
            .Where (t2 => (t2.Table1ID) == t1.ID)
            .DefaultIfEmpty (), 
      (t1, t2) => 
         new  
         {
            C1 = t1.C1, 
            C2 = t2.C2
         }
   )
```